# bind global value into ValidationErrors in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, validation

i try to bind value into ValidationErrors.

i have this method:

```
  isUniqueEmail(control: FormControl): ValidationErrors {
    if (control.value != null) {
        console.log(control.value)
        if(control.value == this.foundEmail){
          console.log("found one");
          return {isUniqueEmail: true}
        }else{
          return null;
        }
      }
  }
```

this method check if control.value (email typing) equal email stored in global variable `this.foundEmail` then we have duplicate email.

My problem is: i can retreive data from foundEmail in this method because this method is private.

this method is located inside export class `exampleComponent` implements OnInit.

Error: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'foundEmail')`

But i check i have data into `foundEmail`

Comment: If we're dealing with context, it should be better if you explain where this `isUniqueEmail` function is located. Is this inside of a class? Where this *this* come from? Did he come from the parent function?

Comment: inside export class exampleComponent implements OnInit. @NicolasDellazzeri

Comment: Another thing, in JS you don't need to check if some value is different from null. There are [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) and [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values, which makes your `if(control.value != null)` statement redundant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The validator function gets called from the `FormControl` so its context is not bound to the class you're defining the method on. You need to manually bind `isUniqueEmail()` to `this`.

Two options:

1. Use [bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) when defining the FormControl:

   ```
   name: new FormControl("", [
       this.isUniqueEmail.bind(this),
   ]),
   ```
2. Define your validator as [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
isUniqueEmail = (control: FormControl) => {
    if (control.value != null) {
        console.log(control.value)
        if(control.value == this.foundEmail){
          console.log("found one");
          return {isUniqueEmail: true}
        }else{
          return null;
        }
      }
  }
```

Comment: amazing !!! thank you